# How to convert PowerPoint.Shape to Bitmap?

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

I am writing an PowerPoint VSTO Addin (C#) and faced the following problem:

How to convert PowerPoint.Shape object to Bitmap or Image?

Comment: what have you tried? can you please add any attempts made so far?

Comment: Actually, I investigated the Microsoft documentation and also the Shape class methods, but found nothing similar to converting to image. VSTO development is a quite narrow field and some techniques are not described at all...

Answer (score 2):

Here is some documentation i found about the PowerPoint.Shape class, it has a function named Export, maybe it's useful:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ff761596(v%3doffice.14)

EDIT: to specify the format you want to save the shape in, check the PpShapeFormat class documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ff763485%28v%3doffice.14%29), it's the 5th parameter of Shape.Export function.

An example of how you could call the Shape.Export function:

```
Powerpoint.Shape shape;

//TODO: set your shape into the "shape" variable, 

//assuming ScaleWidth and ScaleHeight are in pixels since i didnt test this yet
shape.Export(@"C:\shapes\shape.jpg", PpShapeFormat.ppShapeFormatJPG, 500, 500, PpExportMode.ppScaleToFit);
```

[image]